# Ansible Docker exec failed with docker not found in path?

Tags: docker, ansible

Using docker with ansible, the simulation of a docker exec process failed with an awkward error

```
---
- hosts: centos
  become: true
  tasks:
    - name: create jenkins container
      docker_container:
        name: my_jenkins
        image: jenkins

    - name: add container to inventory
      add_host:
        name: my_jenkins
        ansible_connection: docker
        ansible_user: jenkins
      changed_when: false

    - name: create directory for ssh keys
      delegate_to: my_jenkins
      file:
        path: "/var/jenkins_home/.ssh/jupiter"
        state: directory
```

error

```
TASK [create directory for ssh keys] ***********************************************************************************
fatal: [apollo]: FAILED! => {"msg": "docker command not found in PATH"}
```

Comment: That seems like a pretty clear error.  (The `docker_container` module uses a Python library to directly interact with the Docker daemon.)  Do you think you have a `/usr/bin/docker` or some such?  Would it be better to just inject that directory using a bind mount at container startup time?

Answer (score 1):

"docker command not found in PATH" means that Ansible tried to execute the docker command but the docker executable could not be found. echo $PATH to see the current dir. paths that are searched for executable.

Given that Ansible is able to complete step 1 and 2, my assumption is that the docker daemon did indeed install successfully. So

1. Add the path to the Docker daemon to the systems $PATH Install.
2. Docker into a path that is already included in the $PATH.

Hope this helps out.

Comment: docker client and dockerd daemon are both in the path /usr/bin so they are all available to all users and for python I guess.

Comment: Do a 'which docker' as the user Ansible uses on the remote machine. I am thinking the binary might not be accessible to the user.